# Unable to connect to a .mdf database file in Windows application from client machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, localdb

I am creating a Windows application to maintain the School Students information. I am using a `LocalDB` database and I do have the copies of `<DBName>.MDF` and `<DBName>_Log.LDF`. As Visual Studio along with MSSQLLocalDB already installed in my laptop, I am able to connect to the database and application is just working fine.

I just copied the build files along with DB files in my client machine and tried opening the windows application. But the app returning below errors when it is trying access the database:

> The Underlying Provided Failed to Open".
>   Inner expectation: Server not accessible or not available

I am pretty much sure that my client machine doesn't have any SQL client tools installed, so it quite possible that failing to connect the `.MDF` database file.

Now my questions are:

1. Is it really possible to connect to a `.mdf` database file from Windows application in client machine without installing any big tools? As my client doesn't want to install any big tools on their system
2. If my 1st question answer is Yes, How we can achieve this? Any changes required in my code or config file?
3. If this required any small tools to install in client application, what are they?
4. If `.MDF` database file not at all going to work on client machine, are there any alternatives? Please suggest.

My connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolDBEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\SchoolDB.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You can delete that comment now Eraj - code blocks need to be preceded with a blank line to work correctly.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can't access the mdf file without installing Sql server on the client machine. At least you need to install Sql a server express.

Comment: @halfer thanks for guidelines. i will follow these guidelines to all my future posts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

@Chetan Ranpariya is almost correct. If you are using MS SQL Server - any version - you must have SQL Server installed on the machine where the mdf/ldf files live or at least where they can be accessed by the SQL Server program.

If I read your question correctly, you have MSSQL Installed on your laptop and that is why it works there. You do not have MSSQL installed on the client's computer or network so your calls to the DB fail.

As to what else to use, that question is far too broad. It depends on a lot of factors.

John

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya thanks for your inputs. I am giving try to install SQL server express in one of client machine and test if i can make connection. I will let you know the update soon.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It will be really helpful  if you can explain the other factors which i can decide what other options i can use to connect the database. if you can give an examples, that will be really helpful. appreciate  your help.

Comment: You would need to consider things like the amount of data to be saved - that is the size of the database; what is acceptable performance - that is how fast does the data need to be returned to the client/user; how many clients will be accessing the data simultaneously; what kind of data protection; data encryption.  Someone has already mentioned SQL Express. For some scenarios you could use MS Access. Also look at MySQL which is also free. For VERY small data sets you could also look at using XML which requires no special software. Do a google search on something like "database software"

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya, I was just reading another thread about a similar issue and someone mentioned SQLLite. You might want to take a look at that.